# Is it possible to shrink raid5 software array in a safe way?

Tags: linux, ext4, mdadm, raid5

Is it possible to shrink ext4 filesystem and the underlying raid5 array in a safe way?

I would like to shrink my 15 TB / 6 drive raid array that contains an ext4 filesystem.

Before I do that on live system, I decided to give it a try on a test environment.
I wrote a script that simulates raid+filesystem lifecycle (assemble, mkfs, resize2fs, shrink, ...) but in some cases cases it corrupts the filesystem. The script was run on two different distros (one of them was Centos-8).

I tried to understand the failures and unless I am missing something, mdadm, during raid shrink process (mdadm --grow) knows nothing about the ext4 filesystem and it seems it is not possible to help this tool behave properly.

In my scenario, a script to simulates a process:

1. selects a random number **num_devices** (between 5 and 10) is chosen - that determines number of devices in our test array
2. selects random number **device_size** (between 300 and 350) - size (in MiB) of a single device
3. creates and assembles **/dev/md0** - an RAID 5 array (in my case it was 0.90 metadata) - size of an array is **array_size=($num_devices-1)*$device_size**
4. creates ext4 filesystem on **/dev/md0** and mounts it to **/mnt**
5. copies a reference file (in my case it was one of the kernel images from /boot) **$num_devices** times to **/mnt** (to have some data to validate filesystem integrity) - the filesystem has about 80% of free space avaialable
6. the filesystem is unmounted, fscked (`e2fsck -f`) then shrunk (either `resize2fs -M` for minimum size or `reisze2fs /dev/md0 {calculated_size}`), and fscked again
7. the script waits for mdadm rebuild process to finish (by looking at /proc/mdstat)
8. new array size is calculated: **new_array_size=($num_devices-2)*$device_size**
9. hard disk failure is simulated by `mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --fail /dev/loop3` followed by 
   `mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --remove /dev/loop3`
10. waits for the reshape process to finish

Once the reshape process is finished, /dev/loop3 is marked as removed and another loop device (e.g. /dev/loop2) is marked as spare.

11. the process determines the spare, and re-adds it to an array (`mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --remove  /dev/loop2` followed by `mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/loop2`)
12. script waits for raid rebuild the to finish (watching /proc/mdstat)

At this moment the corrupt occurs:

13. filesystem is mounted again at /mnt
14. md5 checksum comparision between reference file and copies on a shrunk filesystem either succeds or fails for 1-2 files
15. filesystem is unmounted, fscked (`e2fsck -f`), grown to maximum (resize2fs) and fscked again
16. corruptions is still present

Am I doing something wrong or raid5 shrink process is really unsupported? or is 0.90 metadata the reason?

Comment: You described the procedure. For users who want to replicate your results the script code would be useful (not instead of the description, aside of). Maybe even the culprit is some quirk in the script itself. Can we get the code?

Comment: What kind of storage is backing each of your loop devices? A disk partition? A file created with mkfile or fallocate?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: here's a script I am using to test for corruption: https://gist.github.com/adamgolebiowski/9f15681fdabe9eca958ee144414d29b0 

please note it should be run on a test environment

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: I am using loop files created either by dd or fallocate -z